# Creating a Dungeons and Dragons dice roller

Tags: java, dice

I am being tasked to create a Dungeons and Dragons dice rolling program in which four dice are rolled, the highest three numbers are recorded, and the lowest number is put off to the side.

The program needs to use Object Oriented Programming, and that is where I am running into the problem.

Additionally, no nested If statements or loops may be used.

I am trying to figure out how to code each class separately from each other.

I need a class that will run the program itself, one that asks the person using the program how many sets of dice they'd like to roll, a class to actually represent the set of dice rolls, a class to represent the series of dice rolled (this being displaying what Dice 1 rolled, what Dice 2 rolled, etc.), and lastly a class to handle the rolling of a single die.

I know that the output needs to show each set of dice rolled.

The output needs to look like this:

```
Set 1: 11, 12, 3, 1
Set 2: 12, 3, 1, 4
```

And so on.

Also, the main thing that is throwing me off when trying to create this program is that I am being required to make it without and nested if statements or loops.

Comment: Is it required that you use a separate class for each of those actions? You could probably complete this task with just two class, your main task where your main() will be--which can handle the user prompts, handling user input, and recording dice rolls as well as displaying them-- and a dice class with methods for rolling dice.

Comment: If I can condense this down into two classes, it would be great. Less work and less to keep track of. I also forgot to mention that I can't use nested if statements or loops. That is the part that is throwing me off, that is why I don't know how to set this up.

Comment: Is there a finite number of dice sets a user can roll? Meaning, can a user only roll 1, 2, 3 or 4 sets of dice or could a user elect to roll any number of sets?

Comment: The user may roll as many dice as they input. I was thinking to use a Scanner to ask the user how many dice they'ed like to roll, and then use that in a for loop to loop the dice roll as many times as the user says.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood when you said you could not use loops. I thought you were saying you cannot use any loops. You meant you cannot use nested loops correct? If so, I would agree, use a scanner to ask a user how many sets of dice they would like to roll. Then, based on the number of sets to be rolled use that as your loop condition--(e.g. i < setsOfDie). Is each die set the same size or can a user pick how large the set of die being rolled is?

Comment: Could you clarify the difference between" a class to actually represent the set of dice rolls", and  "a class to represent the series of dice rolled"

Comment: @MKreegs Each dice set is the same size. It is a series of four dice that is rolled. The series of four dice equals one set. In each set, the highest three numbers are recorded and the lowest number is displayed as a low roll. For example, if the user rolled a 5, 5, 4, and 1, the output would look like `Set 1: 5, 5, 4 || Low Roll: 1 || Roll Total: 14`

Comment: @jpdymond There are four dice that are rolled in a series and the four dice are complied together into one set. If that can all be done in one class that would be fantastic, just so long as there are no nested if statements or loops. Does that make sense?

Comment: So, now that we know what the specific question is and requirements of the solution are, what type of answer would you like? I assume you do not just want someone to post the code so you can paste it in. Would you like something in the form of sudo code, a general approach to solving the problem, or something else?

Comment: A start would be nice. What classes I should use, how to go about making the code without using nested loops. I have never done any code that hasn't used nested loops so it's throwing me for a loop (no pun intended). Some sudo code would be nice I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution to this problem should be able to be completed using two classes: you main class and a Dice class.

Your main class should have your `main(){}` which will contain the code to prompt a user for input and print out dice rolls.

You likely only needs two methods in your `Dice` class, that is going to be a constructor and a getter for the value of a die.

Your dice constructor can set a roll value of a dice object to a random number from 1 to 6 (assuming you are using a D6 for your DnD rolls) when the die is created. This will save you from needing to call another method to actually "roll" the die.

You can then use the getter for the roll value from your `main()` to get the roll value. This getter only needs to return the value of the roll.

You will need a member variable for your Dice class that can hold the random value generated for a new die--I would suggest an `int` since you will only need integers.

In your `main(){}` you can use a scanner to take the user's input for how many dice sets they would like to be rolled. Based on their input, you could use a for loop where the condition is checked against the user's input. (e.g. `for(int i = 0 ; i <userInput ; i ++)` ). The loop will iterate once for each set of die the user wants to roll.

Inside this loop you could create four `Dice` objects with each iteration of the loop. This will effectively give you four "rolls" since each die is instantiated with a random number.

Assuming you give the member variable that will hold a die's value in your 'Dice' class a name like roll, you could access the die's value through dot notation like this `dice1.roll()` This can be used in your output as well rather than needing to assign the value returned to another variable.

Finally, to check which roll is the lowest, you can use a series of if - else statements to check which roll is the lowest. I would suggest using a condition like the following

`if(dice1.roll() < dice2.roll() && dice1.roll() < dice3.roll() && dice1.roll() < dice3.roll()){
//print your dice rolls. If the condition is true, we know that dice1 had the
//lowest roll
}`

You can then use an else to check if dice2 is the lowest, another else if to check for dice3 and another to check for dice4.

In sudo code your main class might look something like this

```
\\main

\\declare a scanner
\\declare int for user input

\\output: How many dice would you like to roll
\\input user input var is assigned the value of user input


\\for loop checking if i < userInput
   \\Create new dice object dice1
   \\Create new dice object dice2
   \\Create new dice object dice3
   \\Create new dice object dice4

   \\check if dice1 is lowest
       \\print out die rolls, totals, and lowest roll
   \\else if check dice2 is lowest
       \\print out die rolls, totals, and lowest roll
   \\else if check dice3 is lowest
       \\print out die rolls, totals, and lowest roll
   \\else if check dice4 is lowest
       \\print out die rolls, totals, and lowest roll

\\end for loop this loop will iterate how ever many times the user input
    \\each loop will create 4 dice objects with random D6 values
    \\essentially give you 4 "rolls" for each iteration of the loop
```

This main class has no nested loops or if statements.

Your `Dice` class may look something like this

```
\\ Dice

\\declare a private int named something like roll to hold the random value

\\constructor
    \\assign roll a random int value between 1 and 6


\\getter
    \\return the random value
```

That should be enough to get you started.

As an added bonus, if you wanted to get the program to "run" and ask he user for a another set of die and roll them again--over and over until you closed the program--, you could wrap the body of the `main()`, starting just before you prompt the user for input, with a while loop which is always true. This creates an infinite loop (and nested loops so it does not work for your solution). However, this loop will allow your program to "run" until you terminate the console it is running in. Again, this would be if you wanted to use this for your own use, it would not satisfy the requirements of your specific problem if you included the `while(true){}` loop.

I hope this all helps

Mkreegs

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for. However do Else If count as a nested if statement? Other than that this answers most of my questions. I'll get started on this and then come back if I need more help with anything.

Comment: No, an else if is not nested. An else if will only execute if the condition that came before it is false. If they were nested the previous condition would need to be true. The else if is similar to an else statement except you are checking another condition, rather than just saying "if that was not true do this". In english an if/else if might sound like this: 
"If you are a bunny, hop. Else, if you are a kitty, meow. Else if are a dog, woof." A nested if would look like: "If you are a bunny, if you are a kitty, if you are a dog..." Does that make sense?

Comment: My last question. Sense this is for Dungeons and Dragons, the typical rule is roll 4 6 sided dice and drop the lowest roll. In this case there is the added rule of re rolling your lowest roll. What I mean by that is that if the user rolls a 5, 4, 3, and 2, the 2 would be left out as the lowest roll and the 5, 4, and 3 would be added together to make 12. What could I do to force the user to re roll their lowest roll (in this case, the 3)? And by force, I mean force. I don't want the user to have an option to skip this (I don't want anyone cheating).

Comment: Create another dice object in side the appropriate if block and use that new dice objects roll value as the re-roll.  Again, I am just using new object because they are returning a random value each time. You could create a method in the Dice class to re-roll a die. However, you will still be generating a new random number, which is exactly what you are doing each time you create a new dice object.

Comment: Keep in mind, however, this solution would probably not be the best if a user is going to roll 10000000000 sets of dice at one time. By creating and destroying 4 or five dice over and over again, java will be garbage collecting more often. However, I still feel like it is the simplest and shortest solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely need to use the four classes you described, here is a solution:

NOTE: Two ways of avoiding a loop are: a) typing the code in n times (if there are few constant iterations), b) using a recursive method instead.

Main:

- Ask user number of sets
- Use Recursive method to repeat printSet() n times

SetCreator:

- Instantiate a SeriesRoller
- Sort int[], and format it as you described
- getSet() returns String

SeriesRoller:

- Instantiate a DieRoller
- Use recursive method to roll die for times
- getSeries() returns int[]

DieRoller:

- Instantiate a Random
- getRoll() returns number from 1 to 6